# c++11 : easiest way to create a function always returning true to use for a function argument

Tags: function, c++11, lambda

I want to use the following template member function

```
template <typename Entity>
class SomeCollection
{
    // ....

    template <typename Measure, typename Filter>
    Entity maximalEntity(Measure&& measure, Filter&& requirement)
    {
        auto maxEntity = Entity();
        auto maxValue = -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();

        for (auto ent /* some iteration method*/)
        {
            auto measurement = measure(ent);
            if (requirement(ent) && measurement > maxValue)
                std::tie(maxEntity, maxValue) = std::make_tuple { ent, measurement };
        }
        return maxEntity;
    }

    // ...
};
```

What is the best way to call this function from client code without Filter requirement (to just have the maximal element) ?

The best I can come up with is:

```
class Something;
double measure(Something&);
SomeCollection<Something> collection;

auto maximum = collection.maximalEntity(measure, [](const Something&) { return true; });
```

But I guess this lambda function could be improved no ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure how the lambda can be *improved*, but you could define a generic lambda that given any input would return always true (which could also be used here):

```
auto always_true = [](auto&&...) { return true; };
```

and you would use it as:

```
auto maximum = collection.maximalEntity(measure, always_true);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24fc16b8730b1a60)

---

An equivalent implementation for C++11 is the following:

```
struct always_true {
    template<typename... Args>
    bool operator()(Args&&...) const noexcept {
        return true;
    }
};
```

which would then be used as:

```
auto maximum = collection.maximalEntity(measure, always_true{});
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a9709544ff741b9)

Comment: great answer. Just nitpicking (or maybe a matter of style): in C++11 version you could make `struct always_true_t` and then `const always_true_t always_true`

Answer (score 2):

You could create a lambda which returns true and set it as default parameter.

```
auto true_filter = [](const Something& arg){ return true; };
//auto true_filter = [](auto&& arg){ return true; }; if you have c++14
...

template <typename Measure, typename Filter = decltype(true_filter)>
Entity maximalEntity(Measure&& measure, Filter requirement = true_filter)
{

...
auto maximum = collection.maximalEntity(measure);
```

Note the `Filter` has changed from `Filter&&`. I have not get it to work with rvalue refs here.

Though having it explicitly stated is probably better design. Just an option to have it "shorter"

Comment: Polymorphic lambdas were added in C++14, the question is tagged C++11. The reason you couldn't get it to work with an rvalue ref is that you defined `always_true` as an lvalue. If you make the default template argument an lvalue ref then `Filter&&` will work, i.e. `decltype(true_filter)&`

Answer (score 1):

C++14:

```
template<class T>
auto always() {
  return [](auto&&...)->T{return {};};
};
```

or in C++11:

```
template<class T>
struct always {
  template<class...Args>
  T operator()(Args&&...)const{ return {}; }
};
```

use:

```
collection.maximalEntity(measure, always<std::true_type>());
```

this has the advantage that the truth of the lambda involved is encoded in the type system, which makes it marginally easier for compilers to optimize its behavior.

This also lets you do `always<std::false_type>` or `always<std::integral_constant<int, 42>>()` etc.

In C++17 I'd do:

```
template<auto x>
auto always() {
  return [](auto&&)->std::integral_constant<decltype(x), x>
  { return {}; };
}
```

which permits `always<true>()` and `always<42>()` (and maybe `always<nullptr>()`?).